# Função para resetar o timer não está funcionando

Tags: java, html, css, front-end

Fiz um pomodoro timer, usando html, css e javascript. Criei uma função para resetar o timer quando clicar no botão de reset, deveria resetar os minutos e os segundos, e no caso de estar no break resetaria o break também, porém só funcionou para os segundos e eu não entendi o motivo.
O código js está abaixo:

```
let workTittle = document.getElementById('work');
let breakTittle = document.getElementById('break');

let workTime = 25;
let breakTime= 5;

let seconds = "00"

//display
window.onload = () => {
    document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML = workTime;
    document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = seconds;

    workTittle.classList.add('active');
}

//start timer
function start(){
    document.getElementById('start').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('reset').style.display = "block"
   
    seconds = 59;

    let workMinutes = workTime -1;
    let breakMinutes = breakTime-1;

    breakCount = 0;
    let timerFunction = () => {
        document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML = workMinutes;
        document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = seconds; 
        document.getElementById('titulo').innerHTML = workMinutes+":"+seconds;

        seconds = seconds - 1;
        if(seconds === 0){
            workMinutes=workMinutes-1;
            if (workMinutes === -1) {
                if(breakCount % 2 === 0){
                    workMinutes = breakMinutes;
                    breakCount++;

                    workTittle.classList.remove('active');
                    breakTittle.classList.add('active');
                }else{
                    workMinutes = workTime;
                    breakCount++;
                    breakTittle.classList.remove('active');
                    workTittle.classList.add('active');
                }
            }
            seconds=59;
        }
        if(workMinutes<10) workMinutes= '0'+workMinutes;
        if(seconds<10) seconds= '0'+seconds;
    }
    setInterval(timerFunction, 1000);
}
function reset(){
    workMinutes = 24;
    breakMinutes= 5;
    breakTime = 5;
    breakCount= 0;
    seconds = 59;
}
```

> Citação

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As variáveis ***workMinute*** e ***breakMinutes*** estão dentro da função ***start()*** então as variáveis só existem dentro do escopo da função. Basicamente você está tentando resetar o valor de uma variável que a função ***reset()*** não encontra.

modifique o código para:

```
let workTittle = document.getElementById('work');
let breakTittle = document.getElementById('break');

let workTime = 25;
let breakTime= 5;
let workMinutes = 0;
let breakMinutes = 0;
let seconds = "00"

//display
window.onload = () => {
    document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML = workTime;
    document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = seconds;

    workTittle.classList.add('active');
}

//start timer
function start(){
    document.getElementById('start').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('reset').style.display = "block"
   
    seconds = 59;

    workMinutes = workTime -1;
    breakMinutes = breakTime-1;

    breakCount = 0;
    let timerFunction = () => {
        document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML = workMinutes;
        document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = seconds; 
        document.getElementById('titulo').innerHTML = workMinutes+":"+seconds;

        seconds = seconds - 1;
        if(seconds === 0){
            workMinutes=workMinutes-1;
            if (workMinutes === -1) {
                if(breakCount % 2 === 0){
                    workMinutes = breakMinutes;
                    breakCount++;

                    workTittle.classList.remove('active');
                    breakTittle.classList.add('active');
                }else{
                    workMinutes = workTime;
                    breakCount++;
                    breakTittle.classList.remove('active');
                    workTittle.classList.add('active');
                }
            }
            seconds=59;
        }
        if(workMinutes<10) workMinutes= '0'+workMinutes;
        if(seconds<10) seconds= '0'+seconds;
    }
    setInterval(timerFunction, 1000);
}
function reset(){
    workMinutes = 24;
    breakMinutes= 5;
    breakTime = 5;
    breakCount= 0;
    seconds = 59;
}
```

e funcionara normalmente.